# Call function to update 'onclick' parameters after 3 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code and not everything working as expected:

### ORYGINAL CODE - START

```
function reminder_set_now$id(this_val,this_change) {
$( '#set_reminder' ).on({
    mousedown: function() {
        $(this).data('timer', setTimeout(function() {
              if (this_change = 1) {
                       alert('1!');
                        sr_change_click_e1();   
                    } 
                    else if (this_change = 2) {
                       alert('2!');
                        sr_change_click_e2();   
                    }
                    else {
                        alert('3!');
                         sr_change_click_e3();  
                    }

        }, 3000));
    },
    mouseup: function() {
        clearTimeout( $(this).data('timer') );
    }
});
}

function sr_change_click_e1() {
   var clickfun = $("#set_reminder").attr("onClick");
   var funname = clickfun.substring(0,clickfun.indexOf("("));       
   $("#set_reminder").attr("onclick",funname+"(\'2\',\'2\')");
}

function sr_change_click_e2() {
   var clickfun = $("#set_reminder").attr("onClick");
   var funname = clickfun.substring(0,clickfun.indexOf("("));       
   $("#set_reminder").attr("onclick",funname+"(\'3\',\'3\')");
}

function sr_change_click_e3() {
   var clickfun = $("#set_reminder").attr("onClick");
   var funname = clickfun.substring(0,clickfun.indexOf("("));       
   $("#set_reminder").attr("onclick",funname+"(\'1\',\'1\')");
}
```

```
<a href="#" id="set_reminder" onClick="reminder_set_now'.$id.'(\'1\',\'1\')">Reminder</a>
```

---

ORYGINAL CODE - END

And 2 issues with it:

1. Alert1 doesnt display after I hold for 3 seconds for the first time but if I click on it first and then hold it with the second click.
2. every other hold display always alert1 not 2 and then 3

### UPDATED CODE - START

```
function reminder_set_now(this_val,this_change) {
var t_change = this_change;
$( '#set_reminder' ).on({
    mousedown: function() {
        $(this).data('timer', setTimeout(function() {
              if(t_change == 1) {
                        sr_change_click_e1();   
                    } 
                    else if (t_change == 2) {
                        sr_change_click_e2();   
                    }
                    else {
                         sr_change_click_e3();  
                    }

        }, 3000));
    },
    mouseup: function() {
        clearTimeout( $(this).data('timer') );
    }
});
}

function sr_change_click_e1() {
   var clickfun = $("#set_reminder").attr("onmousedown");
   var funname = clickfun.substring(0,clickfun.indexOf("("));       
   $("#set_reminder").attr("onmousedown",funname+"(\'2\',\'2\')");
}
function sr_change_click_e2() {
   var clickfun = $("#set_reminder").attr("onmousedown");
   var funname = clickfun.substring(0,clickfun.indexOf("("));       
   $("#set_reminder").attr("onmousedown",funname+"(\'3\',\'3\')");
}
function sr_change_click_e3() {
   var clickfun = $("#set_reminder").attr("onmousedown");
   var funname = clickfun.substring(0,clickfun.indexOf("("));       
   $("#set_reminder").attr("onmousedown",funname+"(\'1\',\'1\')");
}
```

```
<a href="#" id="set_reminder" onClick="reminder_set_now'.$id.'(\'1\',\'1\')">Reminder</a>
```

---

UPDATED CODE - END

Any suggestions where I am wrong please.

Comment: The click event is fired when a mousedown and mouseup occur on the same element sequentially. The time between those events doesn't matter. If you want to trigger an event when pushing the mouse button down, you have to use `mousedown` event.

Comment: jQuery [.on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/) expects an `event` (type String) see: https://api.jquery.com/on/ as first parameter but you are passing an object.

Comment: @Teemu Makes no difference if I call onmousedown instead of onclick across the code.

@caramba if I change function to state ```$( '#set_reminder' ).on(
    'mousedown', function() {``` it makes no difference code still work exactly as it was before the change.

Comment: So after some more tests it does looks to me that ```sr_change_click_e2``` is always called no other functions hence why not working as expected in point 2 of my initial question. Any suggestions for that?

Comment: Point 2 is not done. I have forgot about the var so added in main function ```var t_change = this_change;``` and then check ```if(t_change==x) does the trick.

Function still however doesn't fire on first mousedown and also when I have allert in each ```if```` check then it looks like its called every time x the number of previous calls which is weird.

Ii will update question now.